# DLookup, If-Then, Forms, and Time

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table called Crit with a Store column and a TimeToRun column.

I created a Form with an interval that when triggered compares the current time to the time in the TimeToRun column in my table and fires another function called SendCC(), passing along the Store string as an argument.  This is my code:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

Dim storecode As String

If Time = DLookup("TimeToRun", "Crit") Then
storecode = DLookup("[Store]", "Crit", "[TimeToRun] = " & Time)
SendCC (storecode)
End If

End Sub
```

I have the column set as a Date/Time data format, so there shouldn't be a mismatch.  However, as I F8 through my code even if one of my times is set to the current time it never goes into the loop.

Please help!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a delta. Figure out what your upper and lower wiggle room would be for two times to be 'equal'. That's your delta. Program that into your query.

p-code:

storecode = DLookup("[Store]", "Crit", "abs([TimeToRun] - Time) < " & delta)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in your `DLookup` call here:

```
If Time = DLookup("TimeToRun", "Crit") Then
```

From the context of the question it is clear that `Crit` has multiple records. But this call will always return the `TimeToRun` of the **first** record, because there is no criteria.

So you will only check against the first entry.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

    Dim storecode As String
    Dim Moment As Date

    Moment = Time
    If DateDiff("s", Moment, DLookup("TimeToRun", "Crit")) = 0 Then
        storecode = DLookup("[Store]", "Crit", "DateDiff('s', [TimeToRun], #" & Format(Moment, "hh\:nn\:ss") & "#) = 0)")
        SendCC storecode
    End If

End Sub
```

However, as already mentioned, the first *DLookup* will always find the same *TimeToRun*.